# How do I filter for a items that occurred in a particular date only. [SQL]

Tags: sql

What do I put in the `WHERE` clause to filter for purchases only from December?

```
SELECT CAST(date AS date) AS date_only,
       purchase_price
FROM customer_data.customer_purchase
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: December 2021, or any year?

Comment: edit question and show table DDL and tag with db platform

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results?

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE MONTH(ColumnWithDate) = 12
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.